# Selenium Standalone with CORS

Tags: node.js, selenium, cors, webdriver-io

I am currently using webdriver io via nodejs with selenium standalone, which all works fine until I try to do CORS based requests. I am currently using firefox as the test browser and it throws an error due to the CORS request to another domain.

The server is configured to return the correct headers for CORS and the XHR object is configured to allow CORS. I know these work as when I am manually using the site via firefox/chrome it works as expected, however when I am testing it just seems to blow up, which baffles me as the server and client are configured for CORS, and there is no HTTPS involved in the current tests.

So is there anything special I have to do to get CORS working in the test browsers? I know Selenium boots the browsers up in its own profile but I cannot find any details relating to cors in the configuration for the browser settings, nor can I find any dependentFeatures related to the CORS implementations.

I am happy to provide more information if it would help yield an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, CORS is working in your browsers, but due to how Selenium works and due to your application logic they could conflict a bit.

I would advice to turn CORS check off only for Selenium.

For Chrome it will be easy to turn off CORS checks by adding "disable-web-security" to capabilities.
For Firefox it will be "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" preference (NOT a capability). For example using https://github.com/saadtazi/firefox-profile-js

```
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile'),
    webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

var fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setPreference("security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy", false);

fp.encoded(function(prof) {

    var client = webdriverjs.remote({
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'firefox',
            firefox_profile: prof
        }
    });

    client
        .init()
        .url('http://stackoverflow.com/')
        .end();

});
```

Comment: when you say a preference not a capability, where would I set that?

Comment: In fact it's a capability, but with the specific name. If you are using wedbriverio I would advise you to use https://github.com/saadtazi/firefox-profile-js for that purposes (will update how - in an answer). I don't remember how it's called for ff, should look at selenium website, for Chrome for example it's "preferences" object array :)

Comment: Will check it out tomorrow and provide the answer if it fixes it, thanks for taking the time out to answer

Comment: Just tell if it will help, on tuesday i'll be able to look my code on another notebook (i'm using webdriver.io there) and will tell you with better examples then here :)

Comment: Seems to work now, I get the correct 401 responses rather than the CORS errors.

Comment: How to apply the same in Java.